# Is a shared library dynamically or statically linked?

Tags: shared-library, dynamic-linking

I have a trivial static library prepared from two object files

```
ld -shared -o libfoobar.so foo.o bar.o
```

When I check the type of the library file with the `file` utility, it reports that the library is dynamically linked:

```
file libfoobar.so 
# libfoobar.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
```

When I ask the same (?) question using `ldd`, it reports that the library is statically linked:

```
ldd libfoobar.so 
#    statically linked
```

How should I reconcile these two outputs?

---

```
uname -a
# Linux leo 4.15.0-124-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:54:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does your shared library link to anything else? If not, `ldd`'s going to call it statically linked.

Comment: @muru No, it does not. At the moment, I am not even concerned about which report is right. I am concerned that they are different.

Comment: I don't see it as particularly concerning. Your file is built in a way that allows it to be dynamically linked, which is what `file` reports, but it doesn't actually link to anything, which is what `ldd` reports.

Comment: @muru `file` reports that it _is_ dynamically linked, not that it _can be_ dynamically linked.

Comment: Yes, and that's a consequence of how the library was built (to clarify: when I said "allows to be dynamically linked", I meant that it could link to other libraries, not that other things can dynamically link to it)